# Fluxbox + lightdm on ubuntu 20.04 running on BBG

Tags: 20.04, lightdm, arm, fluxbox

I have configured ubuntu 20.o4 LTS for ARM Cortex (BBG) processor, connected LCD. I am trying to configure fluxbox and the lightdm window manager. Fluxbox and lightdm is not showing login window. When i see status of the lightdm it says Active and running but
I have the below errors:

```
$ lightdm --test-mode --debug
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.30.0, UID=0 PID=2959
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/custom.conf
[+0.02s] DEBUG:   [SeatDefaults] is now called [Seat:*], please update this configuration
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Using Xephyr for X servers
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Registered seat module local
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.09s] DEBUG: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation local (GLocalVfs) for ?gio-vfs?
[+0.14s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.14s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.14s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.15s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.15s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating user session
[+0.17s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.17s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+0.33s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.33s] DEBUG: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 
[+0.37s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.37s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.37s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.38s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Can't launch X server Xephyr, not found in path
[+0.38s] DEBUG: XServer 0: X server stopped
[+0.38s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+0.38s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+0.38s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Can't create display server for automatic login
[+0.38s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+0.39s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+0.39s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.39s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.39s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.40s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.40s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.40s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Can't launch X server Xephyr, not found in path
[+0.41s] DEBUG: XServer 0: X server stopped
[+0.41s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+0.41s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+0.42s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Can't create display server for greeter
[+0.42s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+0.42s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+0.42s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping
[+0.42s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopped
[+0.42s] DEBUG: Failed to start seat: seat0
```

When trying to run fluxbox using startfluxbox it says "could not connect display "

Appreciate your input.

Thanks,
Mrudula

Comment: You have to try `sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service` and then find Fluxbox session on LightDM login screen.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I tired but did not work.